# How can I compile the Jeromq package, the java implementation of ZeroMQ

Tags: java, linux, compilation, zeromq, jeromq

Jeromq is a java implementation of ZeroMQ. 
I am making some changes to the communication(TCP, UDP...), and I want to compile Jeromq in Linux, what is the command that can compile the Jeromq package.
Knowing that I am running it using the following command:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=guide.hwserver -Dexec.classpathScope=test

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Now I am modifying the code, how can I use the UDP feature in Jeromq?